# tikz pin label creating too much space inside math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is about tikz, as below, I want to add a label "reliability factor" for a term (`$z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$`) inside a math environment. But it create too much space in front and behind that term. How can I reduce the space?

Thanks

```
CI= $\bar{X}- \tikz[baseline=-1.2pt]{\node(A406)[node distance=1cm,pin={[pin edge={red, dashed,<->},align=left,font=\tiny]90: reliability\\factor}]{$z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$};} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} <  \mu  < \bar{X}+z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, make the snippet a full (short) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `\tikz` part in a box with the width of just the actual node content, such that the actual width of the tikz part is ignored. For that, you can e.g. use the command defined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268475/103046):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\stextwidth
\newcommand\makesamewidth[3][c]{%
  \settowidth{\stextwidth}{#2}%
  \makebox[\stextwidth][#1]{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
    CI= $\bar{X}-\makesamewidth{$z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$}{\tikz[baseline=-1.2pt]{\node(A406)[node distance=1cm,pin={[pin edge={red, dashed,<->},align=left,font=\tiny]90: reliability\\factor}]{$z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$};}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} <  \mu  < \bar{X}+z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is better, IMO, to annotate above math rather than include annotations as part of math. To this end, the `tikzmark` library can be used to mark some points to refer to them later when making your drawings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

$\text{CI} = \bar{X}- z\tikzmark{p}_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < \mu < \bar{X}+z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[<->,dashed,red]([yshift=10pt]pic cs:p)--++(0,3ex)node[align=center,font=\tiny,black,above]{reliability\\ factor};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you still prefer your syntax, you can simply add `\makebox[0pt]{<the picture>}` and pull the math out of the node contents.

```
$\text{CI} =\bar{X}- z\makebox[0pt]{\tikz{\node(A406)[pin={[pin edge={red, dashed,<->},align=center,font=\tiny]90: reliability\\factor}]{};}} _{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} <  \mu  < \bar{X}+z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $
```

The same result is obtained as above.