# Different alignments in alignat environment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, alignat

I have the following latex code to write down a linear program:

```
\begin{alignat}{5} 
  \tag{$L(\mu)$} L(\mu) =  & \,\textrm{min}  && \,\sum_{h \in H} c_h x_h
  - \sum_{a \in A} \mu_a \sum_{h in H(a)} x_h
  + \sum_{a \in A} \mu_a y_a \\
  &&&- \sum_{t \in T} \mu_t \sum_{h \in H(t)} x_h
  + \sum_{t \in T} \mu_t       \nonumber    \\ 
  \tag{vehicle-flow}      &\textrm{s.t.} && \sum_{ a\in A(v)^{out}} y_a  &= \sum_{a \in A(v)^{in} } y_a  & \forall\, v \in V\\  
  \tag{x-space}           &              && 0                            &\leq x_{h} \leq 1              &\forall\, h \in H \\
  \tag{y-space}           &              && 0                            &\leq y_{a} \leq 1              &\forall\, a \in A 
 \end{alignat}$
```

As we can see, the length of the first equation leads to a bad alignment for the equations below.
[image]

What I want to achieve:

1. align "min" with "s.t."
2. break the min-equation so that it does not become to long
3. align the last three equations amongst themselves without extensive white space
4. I don't want to do that by adding more alignment tabs to the first equation which would give me odd spacing between the sums
5. I had a look into split environments but split does not allow me to have individual tags on my equations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *cheat* more things between two alignment tabs without increasing their horizontal separation by putting stuff into `\makebox` blocks. The following example shows how you can use that to arrange your formulas in the way you want*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength\stextwidth
\newcommand\makesamewidth[3][c]{%
  \settowidth{\stextwidth}{#2}%
  \makebox[\stextwidth][#1]{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    L(\mu)=\min&\makebox[0pt][l]{$\displaystyle\sum_{h \in H} c_h x_h- \sum_{a \in A} \mu_a \sum_{h \in H(a)} x_h+ \sum_{a \in A} \mu_a y_a$} \tag{$L(\mu)$} \\
    &\makebox[0pt][l]{$\displaystyle- \sum_{t \in T} \mu_t \sum_{h \in H(t)} x_h + \sum_{t \in T} \mu_t$} \notag \\
    \makesamewidth[l]{$\min$}{s.t.}&\sum_{ a\in A(v)^{\textrm{out}}} y_a = \sum_{a \in A(v)^{\textrm{in}} } y_a&&\,\forall\, v \in V \tag{vehicle-flow} \\
    &&\makebox[0pt][r]{$0\leq x_{h} \leq 1$}&\,\forall\, h \in H \tag{x-space} \\
    &&\makebox[0pt][r]{$0\leq y_{a} \leq 1$}&\,\forall\, a \in A \tag{y-space}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(I wasn't sure how you wanted the last three equations to be aligned, so I aligned them at the `\forall` sign).

Credits for `\makesamwidth` go to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268475/103046).